# 3Ds MAx Script for Reading Pixels from an image

Tags: scripting, bitmap, pixel, 3dsmax

We are trying to read the pixels from an uploaded Bitmap image, yet the line 
aBrightness = (0.2126*aPixel[1].red) + (0.7152*aPixel[1].green) + (0.0722*aPixel[1].blue) always gives an error saying "Unknown property: "red" in undefined".

Our current script is:

```
aBitmap = selectBitMap caption:"Select a Bitmap"
Print(aBitmap.height)
Print(aBitmap.width)
aLength = aBitmap.height
aWidth = aBitmap.width

for i = 0 to (aLength - 10) by 10 do
(
for j = 0 to (aWidth - 10) by 10 do
(
    Print(i)
    Print(j)
    aPixel = getPixels aBitmap [i,j] 1
    aBrightness = (0.2126*aPixel[1].red) + (0.7152*aPixel[1].green) + (0.0722*aPixel[1].blue)
    aBox = box pos:[i,j,0] width:0.1 length:0.1 height:aBrightness
)
)
```

We would really appreciate any help regarding this script.

Answer (score 0):

You have your coordinates wrong. The X value goes first.

It should be

```
APixels = Getpixels aBitmap [j, i] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if aPixel is undefined before using it.

```
aPixel = getPixels aBitmap [i,j] 1
if (aPixel == undefined) do ( format "ERROR!!! [%,%]\n" i, j to:listener; continue )

aBrightness = (0.2126*aPixel[1].red) + (0.7152*aPixel[1].green) + (0.0722*aPixel[1].blue)
```

This might help you figure where the bug is. Often a function will return 'undefined' to a variable so you need to check if it is undefined. In this case, once you fix the bug, you can remove this type of code since you will have eliminated undefined behavior. Notice I used "format" instead of "print", this is much nicer to use for just a tiny extra code.

I see two suspicious things to check.

1) Most indexing in maxscript starts with 1 not 0. Check the documentation.

2) As Rotem pointed out, [x,y], not [y,x]